# Unexpected keyword 'val' in definition

Tags: f#

Learning F# as part of my course, and can do some cool things, but something has been bugging me, whenever I use the val keyword, I get an error. I think it could be due to not declaring something in script, but I don't really know.

```
module Prime
#light

let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];; 
val nums : list<int> 
let rec sum list = 
    match list with 
    | h::tail -> (sum tail) + h 
    | [] -> 0 
    val sum : list<int> -> int
```

I get (line 5):

```
  Error 1   Unexpected keyword 'val' in definition . Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `val` keyword in F# (unlike 'val' in ML) is used to declare a field in a **class or structure type** without initializing it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx

if you want to define mutable value in the Module you can use

```
let mutable...
```

By the way, if you define the value with the same name (like 'nums') twice or more times then the effective value for the compiler will be latest defined in the scope.

Comment: True, but not the answer. It is merely coincidental that the `val` of this question, which is output of fsi, is also a keyword. I propose to delete this answer, since people searching for this probably aren't looking for the rather obscure keyword for explicit fields.

Comment: Sorry cannot agree with you. He is wandering "whenever I use the 'val' keyword, I get an error." The compiler error he mentioned clearly shows that he want to use this declaration in F# program (maybe copied from FSI output). My answer is about where in F# 'val' keyword is valid and supposed to be used in F#.

Answer (score 1):

So actually, I had misread the coursework set out, annoyingly the papers use val to define what the expected output of the function is, as opposed to using it as the keyword it is meant to be. Hence my confusion and lots of head scratching.

Comment: That's what I suspected from the code. As a side-note, `#light` has been the default since F# 2.0, there is no need to add it anymore.

Comment: The documents you have been reading didn't use val to *define* output, but rather added intermediate output, probably from an old version of F# interactive. See my answer for details.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like *F# interactive output mixed in with code*.

If I type this into FSI:

```
let nums = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
```

The output is

```
val nums : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Note that `;;` is where FSI parses and runs input. You wouldn't have this in non-interactive code. The output might differ because of an older version or editing, but nontheless, it doesn't belong in code.

Coincidentally, `val` is also a rarely used [F# keyword for explicit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx). Hence the strange error message.

Answer (score 0):

The val keyword is used to declare a field ; it must be used inside a type definition (class or structure). Since in your code the variable **nums** is already defined and as the list type inferred by F# type inference engine, there is no need for your val line.

An example of val keyword usage is (from msdn) :

```
type MyType() =
    let mutable myInt1 = 10
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable myInt2 : int
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable myString : string
    member this.SetValsAndPrint( i: int, str: string) =
       myInt1 <- i
       this.myInt2 <- i + 1
       this.myString <- str
       printfn "%d %d %s" myInt1 (this.myInt2) (this.myString)
```